# Populate or not based on a condition mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a following schema in mongoose,

```
Schema = new Schema({
    category = { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
    subCategory = { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'subCategory' },
    subSubCategory = { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'subSubCategory' },
    name: String
});
```

Now I want to conditionally populate or not `category`, `subCategory`, `subSubCategory` based on a few parameters passed to the controller through `req.query`

```
Schema.find(function(err, data) {
   if(err) { //handle errors }
   if(!data) { //throw 404 }
   res.status(200).json(data); 
})
.populate('category') //execute only if(req.query.populateCategory == true)
.populate('subCategory') //execute only if(req.query.populateSubCategory == true)
.populate('subSubCategory'); //execute only if(req.query.populateSubSubCategory == true)
```

How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mongoose model `find` function returns `Query` instance, which you can use to pipe new functions:

> When a callback function is passed, the operation will be executed immediately with the results passed to the callback. When it is not passed, an instance of Query is returned, which provides a special query builder interface.

```
var query = Schema.find({}); // TODO: add filter

if (req.query.populateCategory == true) {
    query = query.populate('category');
}
if (req.query.populateSubCategory == true) {
    query = query.populate('subCategory');
}
if (req.query.populateSubSubCategory == true) {
    query = query.populate('subSubCategory');
}

query.exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) { //handle errors }
    if (!data) { //throw 404 }
    res.status(200).json(data); 
});
```

Comment: Awesome. I think that should be a single dot in `query = query..populate('subCategory');` and `query = query..populate('subSubCategory');`
@Alexander Mac Thank you.